# Force execution of a Maven phase

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven POM with `pre-integration-test` and `post-integration-test` phases as follows.

```
<execution>
    <id>start-server</id>
    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>start-server</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>stop-running-server</id>
    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>stop-server</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

How do I force `post-integration-test` phase to be executed even when the `pre-integration-test` phase fails? Right now, if `pre-integration-test` phase fails the `post-integration-test` phase doesn't get executed.

Comment: what makes the pre-integration-test phase fail? If you need to rely on the post-integration-phase nothing should fail there. for example the failsafe plugin does not fail a build in the integration-test phase, only within the verify phase. So what breaks the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/

> If you use the Surefire Plugin for running tests, then when you have a
>   test failure, the build will stop at the integration-test phase and
>   your integration test environment will not have been torn down
>   correctly.
>
> The Failsafe Plugin is used during the integration-test and verify
>   phases of the build lifecycle to execute the integration tests of an
>   application. The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the
>   integration-test phase, thus enabling the post-integration-test phase
>   to execute.
>
> NOTE: when running integration tests, you should invoke Maven with the
>   (shorter to type too)